# DataTriggers and default property when using ViewModels, Dependency Properties

Tags: wpf, mvvm, model-view

I have a UserControl and a ViewModel for it.

The UserControl is a simple Button Template, with an Ellipse in it. Basically a round button.

I use the ViewModel as a DataContext for the UserControl. 
The ViewModel has a property called "State" whose value I use as a DataTrigger to change "Colors" of the Ellipse, these "Colors" are Dependency Properties in the UserControl.

Everything seems to work, but I cannot set the Default Colors for the Ellipse and because of that I don`t see anything in the Designer for the UserControl. See attached picture.

I do see the correct colors and the shapes when I place the UserControl on to the main window designer.

I definitely would like to see the shapes in the UserControl with some default values, so its easier to see what I`m working with.

This I believe is something to do with DataBinding "State" value from the ViewModel.

[image]
[image]

Here is the Code : UserControl xaml

```
<UserControl x:Name="thisBtn" x:Class="WpfAppDelMe.Views.CustomButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppDelMe.Views"
         xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:WpfAppDelMe.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:CustButtonViewModel  x:Name="xvm"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid Background="#FF9EE3EA">
    <Button Content="{Binding State}" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" Foreground="#FFD13B3B" Margin="0" >
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                    <Viewbox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <Ellipse Height="300" Width="300" Margin="5">
                            <Ellipse.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}" >
                                    <!-- Below Line does not work! -->
                                    <Setter Property ="Fill" Value="Pink" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="OldLace"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="0">
                                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding ElementName=thisBtn, Path=Color1}"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="1">
                                            <Setter   Property="Fill" Value="{Binding ElementName=thisBtn, Path=Color2}"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Ellipse.Style>
                        </Ellipse>
                    </Viewbox>

                    <!--The content presenter for the button string.
                    Placing this in a view box makes sure of the correct size.-->
                    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="10">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>

</Grid>
```

UserControl .cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfAppDelMe.Views
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for CustXam.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class CustomButton : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for the CustomButton UserControl
    /// View and Model
    /// ViewModel : CustomButtonViewModel
    /// </summary>
    public CustomButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Color1Property = 
DependencyProperty.Register("Color1", typeof(Brush), typeof(CustButton), new 
PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Color2Property = 
DependencyProperty.Register("Color2", typeof(Brush), typeof(CustButton), new 
PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { }; 
 //Null initialization is required because there are no listeners or 
bindings 
 for this.
    private int btnState=0;

    //Button Color 1
    public Brush Color1
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(Color1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Color1Property, value); }
    }

    public Brush Color2
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(Color2Property); }
        set { SetValue(Color2Property, value); }
    }

    public int BtnState
    {
        get
        { return btnState;}

        set
        {
            btnState = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("BtnState");
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            xvm.State = btnState;
        }

      }
  }
}

[![enter image description here][1]][1]ViewModel for the UseControl

using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfAppDelMe.ViewModels
{
/// <summary>
/// View Model class for the CustButton. All logic and calculations happen 
  here.
/// This is also the DataContext for the CustButton
/// 
/// View and Model : CustButton
/// ViewModel : CustButtonViewModel
/// </summary>
internal class CustButtonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CustButtonViewModel()
    {
    }

    private int state;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ICommand clickCommand;
    public ICommand ClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (clickCommand == null)
            {
                clickCommand = new RelayCommand(param => ChangeState(), param => CanChange());
            }
            return clickCommand;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private void ChangeState()
    {
        if (State == 0)
        {
            State = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            State = 0;
        }
    }

    private bool CanChange()
    {
        return true;
    }

    //Button state
    public int State
    {
        get{ return state; }
        set
        {
            state = value;
            OnPropertyChange("State");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// On Property Changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    public void OnPropertyChange(string prop)
    {
       PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You see how you have `d:DesignHeight="300"` and `d:DesignWidth="300"` specified in the UserControl definition to define a design-time height and width? You can do the same thing with the DataContext, by setting `d:DataContext`. There should be plenty of examples online with a google search of something like *"wpf designtime datacontext"*

Comment: This is a code smell.  Does a TextBox have a TextBoxViewModel?  NO.  It has a Text DependencyProperty that *whoever uses the textbox* binds to.  And the object they are binding it to must be free to flow into the DataContext of that TextBox.  By creating a view model for your UserControl, and by setting it in the XAML of your UserControl, you've just broken how data binding is supposed to work.  Don't do that.  Place your UI logic in your codebehind, not in a view model.  MVVM != no codebehind.

Comment: @Will - Yes, you are correct.This is smelly code. This was a test case for a more complex requirement. I don`t intend to use Models and ViewModels for UserControls.

Comment: @Rachel - Thank you for the direction.